# closed balls perserving map between metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be a non-empty metric spaces. Let $F\colon X\to Y$ be such that for any $r>0$ and all $x\in X$ we have $F( B_X(r,x))=B_Y(r,F(x))$ ($B_X(r,x)$ and $B_Y(r,F(x))$ closed balls of radius $r$ in $X$ and $Y$ around $x$ and $F(x)$, respectively). Show the following:-

1. $F$ is surjective;
2. $F$ is continuous;
3. $F$ is open; and
4. if $y_1,y_2\in Y$ and $x_1\in X$ such that $y_1=F(x_1)$, then we can find $x_2\in X$ such that $F(x_2)=y_2$ and $d_X(x_1,x_2)=d_Y(y_1,y_2)$.

---

My attempt is as following:-

1. For any $y\in Y$, pick $x\in X$ and take $r\geq d_Y(y,F(x))$. Then $y\in B_Y(r,F(x))=F(B_X(r,x))$.
2. Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $X$ converging to $x$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $x_j\in B_X(\epsilon,x)$ for any $j> N$. But then $F(x_j)\in F(B_X(\epsilon,x))=B_Y(\epsilon,F(x))$ for $j>N$.
3. **Help is appreciated!** Of course we need to show that $F(U)$ is open for $U\subset X$ open. So for $y\in F(U)$ let $x\in U$ such that $y=f(x)$; find $r>0$ such that $b_X(r,x)=int(B_X(r,x))\subset B_X(r,x)\subset U$. Then we have $b_Y(r,y)\subset B_Y(r,y)=F(B_X(r,x))\subset F(U)$. Where $b_X(r,x)$ and $b_Y(r,y)$ are the open balls of radius $r$ centered at $x$ and $y$, respectively. (Recalling that interiors of closed balls are open balls)
4. Suppose for all $x_2\in F^{-1}(y_2)$ we have $d_X(x_1,x_2)\neq d_Y(y_1,y_2)$. If $d_X(x_1,x_2)<d_Y(y_1,y_2)$ then $y_2\in F(B_X(x_1,d_X(x_1,x_2))=B_Y(y_1,d_X(x_1,x_2))\not\ni y_2$ which is a contradiction. On the other hand if $d_X(x_1,x_2)>d_Y(y_1,y_2)$... I am stuck here!

Comment: I assume you mean for any choice of $x\in X$ and $r>0$?

Comment: @user829347 for which part?

Comment: In the statement of the problem you are trying to solve. As currently written, it could mean for a specific choice of closed ball rather than for any closed ball (I assume you mean the latter)

Comment: @user829347 Yes, this is true. I forgot to write this.

Comment: Once you realize your question may be improved, you may edit it to include the improvement.  Do you know how?

Comment: @Ruy done! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding point (4),  let $r=d(y_1, y_2)$,  so that
$$
  y_2\in B(r, y_1)=B(r, F(x_1))=F(B(r, x_1)).
  $$
So there exists $x_2$ in $B(r, x_1)$, such that $F(x_2)=y_2$.

Letting $s=d(x_1, x_2)$, it is now enough to prove that $s=r$.   Since  $x_2\in B(r, x_1)$,  is obvious that
$$
  d(x_1,x_2)\leq r,
  $$
whence $s\leq r$.
Next notice that $x_2\in B(s,x_1)$, so
$$
  y_2=F(x_2)\in F(B(s,x_1))=B(s,F(x_1))=B(s,y_1),
  $$
so $d(y_1,y_2)\leq s$, that is $r\leq s$,  concluding the proof.

Comment: Nice proof (+1). Was a first a bit perplexed why we don't show that it is injective and then conclude that $(4)$ holds. Until I realized that it does not need to be injective at all.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven. Yes, the whole thing downed upon me when I realized that the projection from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ satisfies the hypotheses!

Comment: @Ruy Thanks for your answer. Is my solution for 3. correct? Thanks

Comment: The worst example that comes to my mind is $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \{0\}$ where we put the discrete metric.

Comment: @ahmd092.  I think it is basically correct, but I worry about your statement that 
$int(B(r, x))=B(r, x)$.

Comment: @Ruy I meant $\subset$, thanks for spotting this.